# Add header and footer row flat file in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a SSIS package which exports data from a query into a flat file, which will be used to import into a data warehouse.  One of my requirements is to add a header row with the current date, and a footer row with total row count.

I would like to do this ideally in one script component or task using C# for tidiness in the package.  I'm a noob when it comes to writing code. How can this be done?  I've looked around on the net but can't seem to find anything close enough to what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I eventually came up with!  It is the cleanest, most simple way I can find of doing this task.  It basically just builds up the header and trailer rows then appends to the dataset.  Seems so simple once you've done it!  It takes a bit of knowledge of C#, however it is well worth it than trying to do it in SQL.

```
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Task
Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
The ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_db04adc927b941d19b3817996ff885c2.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        /*
        The execution engine calls this method when the task executes.
        To access the object model, use the Dts property. Connections, variables, events,
        and logging features are available as members of the Dts property as shown in the following examples.

        To reference a variable, call Dts.Variables["MyCaseSensitiveVariableName"].Value;
        To post a log entry, call Dts.Log("This is my log text", 999, null);
        To fire an event, call Dts.Events.FireInformation(99, "test", "hit the help message", "", 0, true);

        To use the connections collection use something like the following:
        ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
        cm.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;";

        Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.

        To open Help, press F1.
    */

        public void Main()
        {
            const string dirPath = @"C:\SSIS\Dev\";

            DateTime minusoneweek = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);

            DateTime minusoneday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);

            var headerRecord = ("0|" + DateTime.Today.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + "|" + Dts.Variables["LastSequenceNumber"].Value + "|" 
                + Dts.Variables["FileName"].Value) + "|" + minusoneweek.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + "|" + minusoneday.ToString("ddMMyyyy");

            var fileBody = AddHeaderAndFooter.GetFileText(dirPath + "blank.txt");

            var trailerRecord = "9|" + AddHeaderAndFooter.CountRecords(dirPath + "blank.txt").ToString();

            var outPutData = headerRecord + "\r\n" + fileBody + trailerRecord + "\r\n";

            AddHeaderAndFooter.WriteToFile(dirPath + "blank.txt", outPutData);

        }
    }

    public static class AddHeaderAndFooter
    {
        public static int CountRecords(string filePath)
        {

            return (File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Length + 2);  

        }

        public static string GetFileText(string filePath)
        {
            var sr = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.Default);

            var recs = sr.ReadToEnd();

            sr.Close();

            return recs;
        }

        public static void WriteToFile(string filePath, string fileText)
        {

            var sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, false);

            sw.Write(fileText, Encoding.ASCII);

            sw.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with this approach, if your flat file is too big in size it says out of memory exception to read in. How we can avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code you could use for a script task that would allow you to output a CSV with a header and a footer:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace ST_80294de8b8dd4779a54f707270089f8c.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        public void Main()
        {
            int ErrorFlag = 0;

            // Try-Catch block 
            try
            {
                int RowCount = 0;
                bool fireAgain = true;
                string SQLCommandText = "SELECT ColumnA = 1, ColumnB = 'A' UNION SELECT ColumnA = 2, ColumnB = 'B' UNION SELECT ColumnA = 3, ColumnB = 'C';";

                SqlConnection SQLConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LocalHost;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=SSIS-My Package Name;Connect Timeout=600");
                SqlCommand SQLCommand = new SqlCommand(SQLCommandText, SQLConnection);
                SQLCommand.CommandTimeout = 60 * 60;
                SqlDataAdapter SQLDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLCommand);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SQLDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                SQLConnection.Close();
                RowCount = dt.Rows.Count;

                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "DataTable Rows", RowCount.ToString(), "", 0, ref fireAgain);

                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Test.csv", false);

                // Write the header.
                sw.Write("Today's date is " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());

                // Write the column headers.
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                int iColCount = dt.Columns.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
                {
                    sw.Write(dt.Columns[i]);
                    if (i < iColCount - 1)
                    {
                        sw.Write(",");
                    }
                }

                // Write the details.
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                        {
                            sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                        }
                        if (i < iColCount - 1)
                        {
                            sw.Write(",");
                        }
                    }
                    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                }

                // Write the footer.
                sw.Write("Row count: " + RowCount.ToString());

                sw.Close();
            }

            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, "SqlException", e.Message, "", 0);
                ErrorFlag = 1;
            }

            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, "IOException", e.Message, "", 0);
                ErrorFlag = 1;
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Exception", e.Message, "", 0);
                ErrorFlag = 1;
            }

            // Return results. 
            if (ErrorFlag == 0)
            {
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            } 

        }
    }
}
```

You could also do this without resorting to C#, but it would be a little ugly:

1. Variable 1: An Int variable used to assign the number of rows from Data Flow 2.
2. Variable 2: A string variable with an expression that generates a SQL command.  If Variable 1's named RowCount, then here's a sample set of code for it:

   "SELECT ColumnA = '" +  (DT_WSTR, 1252)(@[User::RowCount]) + "', ColumnB = NULL"
3. Data Flow 1: Executes a SQL command to generate the header of the file and outputs to a flat file destination.  Set the "overwrite data in the file" to true.
4. Data Flow 2: Executes a SQL command to generate the details of the flat file.  Set the "overwrite data in the file" to false.  Include a Row Count transformation and assign the value to Variable 1.
5. Data Flow 3: Executes a SQL command to generate the footer of the flat file.  The source should "Set command from variable" and it should execute Variable 2.  Set the "overwrite data in the file" to false.